# Having an eavesdropper guess which graph is the correct one and counting how many times it takes? (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, for-loop, random, counter, gaussian

So the idea is, there are four situations: HH, LL, LH, and HL. Each of those are based on a standard normal RNG (randn(n,1)). An eavesdropper takes measurements and records them; one of them is identical to either of the four. I am trying to write a program such that it counts how many times it takes for the eavesdropper to crack the case, within 1% deviation. The first point for HH might be the same as the first point for LL, for example; this is why the eavesdropper needs to continue taking measurements until the possibilities are eliminated and only one situation remains. Each case has 1000 points:

```
n = 1000;
```

My approach was, taking the difference between the measured case and the four cases:

```
diffHH = M - HH;
diffLL = M - LL;
diffHL = M - HL;
diffLH = M - LH;
```

Then, I wrote four for loops to check for each case:

```
for guesses = 1:1:n
    if (abs(diffHH(guesses)) <= 0.01) 
        if (abs(diffHH(guesses)) <= 0.01) && (abs(diffLL(guesses)) <= 0.01)
            continue;
        elseif (abs(diffHH(guesses)) <= 0.01)&& (abs(diffHL(guesses)) <= 0.01)
            continue;
        elseif (abs(diffHH(guesses)) <= 0.01) && (abs(diffLL(guesses)) <= 0.01)
            continue;
        else
            disp('Eve guesses HH');
            break;
        end
    end
end
for guesses = 1:1:n
    if (abs(diffLL(guesses)) <= 0.01) 
        if (abs(diffLL(guesses)) <= 0.01) && (abs(diffHH(guesses)) <= 0.01)
            continue;
        elseif (abs(diffLL(guesses)) <= 0.01)&& (abs(diffHL(guesses)) <= 0.01)
            continue;
        elseif (abs(diffLL(guesses)) <= 0.01) && (abs(diffLH(guesses)) <= 0.01)
            continue;
        else
            disp('Eve guesses LL');
            break;
        end
    end
end
for guesses = 1:1:n
    if (abs(diffHL(guesses)) <= 0.01) 
        if (abs(diffHL(guesses)) <= 0.01) && (abs(diffHH(guesses)) <= 0.01)
            continue;
        elseif (abs(diffHL(guesses)) <= 0.01)&& (abs(diffLL(guesses)) <= 0.01)
            continue;
        elseif (abs(diffHL(guesses)) <= 0.01) && (abs(diffLH(guesses)) <= 0.01)
            continue;
        else
            disp('Eve guesses HL');
            break;
        end
    end
end
for guesses = 1:1:n
    if (abs(diffLH(guesses)) <= 0.01) 
        if (abs(diffLH(guesses)) <= 0.01) && (abs(diffHH(guesses)) <= 0.01)
            continue;
        elseif (abs(diffLH(guesses)) <= 0.01)&& (abs(diffLL(guesses)) <= 0.01)
            continue;
        elseif (abs(diffLH(guesses)) <= 0.01) && (abs(diffHL(guesses)) <= 0.01)
            continue;
        else
            disp('Eve guesses LH');
            break;
        end
    end
end
```

The guesses seem to keep going up to 1000, and they shouldn't; the four cases are quite different. What exactly am I missing?

Comment: Instead of writing four `for` loops with four distinct variables, why not write one `diffM` variable with 4 entries (along the second or third dimension, however large `m-HH` is), and loop over those four? Saves you copying a block of code four times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"guesses" restarts for every loop; consider using different "guesses" names for each case, such as "guessesHH," "guessesLL," etc.